# Let $f(x,y)={x^2\over2}+{y^2\over2}+x^3+y^3-xy^2-x^2y$. Show that $\exists$ a neighbourhood $E$ of $(0,0)$ $f(x,y)>0\forall (x,y)\in E\setminus(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have proved that $f$ attains local minima at $(0,0)$.
As $\nabla f(0,0)=(0,0)$, $(0,0)$ is a stationary point of $f$.
Then $f_{xx}(0,0)=(1+6x-2y)_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=1$, $f_{xy}(0,0)=(2y+2x)|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=0$, $f_{yx}(0,0)=0$ and $f_{yy}(0,0)=(1+6y-2x)|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=1$.
So, $f_{xx}(0,0)>0$ and $\begin{vmatrix}f_{xx}(0,0)&f_{xy}(0,0)\\f_{yx}(0,0)&f_{yy}(0,0)\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{vmatrix}=1>0$. Hence, by second derivative test $f$ attains local maxima at $(0,0)$. Hence, there exists a neighberhood $E$ of $(0,0)$ such that $f(x,y)\ge0\forall (x,y)\in E$.
 
But how to say $f(x,y)$ is strictly positive in a deleted neighbourhood of $(0,0)$?
I am thinking about any algebraic way of representing $f(x,y)={x^2\over2}+{y^2\over2}+x^3+y^3-xy^2-x^2y$ such that the expression becomes positive. I have tried in the following way-
$2f(x,y)=2(x^3+y^3)+(x^2+y^2)-2xy(x+y)=2(x+y)^3-6xy(x+y)+(x^2+y^2)-2xy(x+y)$
$=2(x+y)^3-8xy(x+y)+x^2+y^2$
$=2(x+y)\{(x+y)^2-4xy\}+x^2+y^2$
$=2(x+y)(x-y)^2+x^2+y^2$
But I am getting to conclusion. Can anyone complete the solution? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=:r$. Then 
$$f(x,y)=r^2\left({1\over2}+c(x,y) r\right)\qquad(r\geq0)$$
with $|c(x,y)|\leq 4$. Here we have estimated $|xy^2|\leq r^3$, and similar. This immediately implies
$$|f(x,y)|>0\qquad\left(0< r<{1\over8}\right)\ .$$